# How to efficiently add a user to all projects in GitLab (programmatically or otherwise)

Tags: git, api, gitlab

I have a GitLab CE server with many projects and I would like to add a user to all projects.

I want to avoid having to do this through the UI (Project -> Settings -> Member -> Add User to Project) if possible as that will take a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to move all of the project under a group. Then adding a new member to the group will grant them access to all of the contained projects. It may be tedious to move all of the projects, but once it is done, it will make member management easier. Also consider making a nested hierarchy of groups if you expect you may want finer-grained permissions in the future.

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/group for instructions.

From the "Add users to a group" section of the linked page:

> A benefit of putting multiple projects in one group is that you can
>   give a user to access to all projects in the group with one action.
>
> Add members to a group by navigating to the group’s dashboard and
>   clicking **Members**.
>
> Select the permission level, and add the new member. You can also set
>   the expiring date for that user; this is the date on which they will
>   no longer have access to your group.
>
> Consider a group with two projects:
>
> - On the **Group Members** page, you can now add a new user to the group.
> - Now, because this user is a **Developer** member of the group, they automatically gets **Developer** access to **all projects** within that group.
>
> To increase the access level of an existing user for a specific
>   project, add them again as a new member to the project with the
>   desired permission level.

Comment: Im getting a little confuse. if i add a project to a group and group privilege was developer and in this group is a user that has maintainer privilege to group , what is  user privileges on my project ? (sorry is a little complicated )

Comment: From https://gitlab.analog.com/help/user/permissions, "If a user is both in a group's project and the project itself, the highest permission level is used." Is that what you were asking?

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use the GitLab [Projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html) and [Members](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html) API to achieve this.

First do a `GET` request against the `/projects` API to get a list of all projects.

Then do a `POST` against the`/projects/:id/members` API for each project you want to add the member to.

You can see an example of the `POST` request on that [page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html)

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" --data "user_id=1&access_level=30" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/:id/members
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is for audit consider an Auditor access level.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auditor_users.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30556327)