# How to add all users to a project, including new ones?

Tags: gitlab

I would like to setup a sandbox project in my school GitLab server (self-hosted, free), that all users, especially new ones, can use to test whatever they need.

How can I add all users to the same project?

I already read [this releated question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57076376/771469) (that asks the opposite), but it only partially help; the most useful answer tells me to use the API, which is good if I want to add all *current* users to a project, but I also want to add new ones.

Is there a way to add a user to a project, triggered by that user being confirmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One builtin method would be to use [system hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/system_hooks.html). For example, you can create a hook that responds to `user_create` events and adds the user to the project.

Another way may be just to run a scheduled CI pipeline that scripts this or similar automation (e.g. cron job on the server or whatever).

You can use the [users list API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#list-users) to enumerate all current users in your GitLab instance (requires admin privileges). You can also use the [project membership API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html#list-all-members-of-a-group-or-project) to enumerate all members of the project. You can compare the two results to find any users that need to be added.

Pseudocode:

```py
project_members = get_project_members(project_id=1234) # project members API
for user in get_all_gitlab_users():  # list users API
    if user not in project_members:
        add_project_member(user=user, project_id=1234)
```

Comment: Excellent, I'll do a bit of both: use the API for the current users and a hook for the future ones. Thanks!